# Integer Value Right Padding in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Step1: I have a table called XYZ which contains following integer columns:

```
 ID      A          B          C
 1    201507    20150810   20150311
 2    20150812  201509     201510
```

I need to write a SQL query where if any values of A, B, and C is smaller than 8 digits then I need to consider it as 8 digits by adding zeros to the right of the value for step2 (I am not allowed to update the table.). For example:

```
 ID      A            B          C
 1    20150700    20150810   20150311
 2    20150812    20150900   20151000
```

How to add zeros to the right of the integer values through SQL query?

Step 2: I need to find for each record `A<B, B<C` or not. Please let me know how to write the query. I am using PostgreSQL. Thank you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use trigger? If yes, a before insert trigger can be used to check the value of insert and multiply by 10 until it reaches 8 digits.

Comment: What is the expected result for Step 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rpad()` to add trailing zeros, then cast the result back to an integer:

```
select id, 
       rpad(a::text, 8, '0')::int, 
       rpad(b::text, 8, '0')::int, 
       rpad(c::text, 8, '0')::int
from the_table;
```

To avoid repeating the expressions, use a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  select id, 
         rpad(a::text, 8, '0')::int as a, 
         rpad(b::text, 8, '0')::int as b, 
         rpad(c::text, 8, '0')::int as c
  from the_table
) t
where a < b or b < c --<< change that to the condition you want
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CAST(2015 AS VARCHAR(10))+REPLICATE('0',8-LEN(2015))

SELECT  2015 *(CAST('1'+REPLICATE('0',8-len(2015))  AS INT))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not allowed to change the type to VARCHAR. Values should be an integer.

Comment: Hi, i updated solution as you like without converting column as varchar

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```
select
ID,
A = LEFT(cast(a as varchar(100)+'00000000',8),
b = LEFT(cast(b as varchar(100)+'00000000',8),
C = LEFT(cast(c as varchar(100)+'00000000',8)
from xyz
```

Comment: If columns are integers, zeros will be implicitly converted to compatible type (int), so it will be converted to zero, so `a+'00000000' = a`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I have added a cast statement

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select cast(left(cast(A as varchar(20)) + '00000000', 8) as int) as [A],
       cast(left(cast(B as varchar(20)) + '00000000', 8) as int) as [B],
       cast(left(cast(C as varchar(20)) + '00000000', 8) as int) as [C]
from TABLE_NAME
```

If you want to avoid any casting, this might be solution:

```
select case when 8 - LEN(A) > 0 then A * Power(10, (8 - LEN(A))) else A end as [A],
       case when 8 - LEN(B) > 0 then B * Power(10, (8 - LEN(B))) else B end as [B],
       case when 8 - LEN(C) > 0 then C * Power(10, (8 - LEN(C))) else C end as [C]
from MY_TABLE
```